# KeOps (Kernel Operations on the GPU) on Windows

Tags: python, windows, gpu

When installing [KeOps](https://github.com/getkeops/keops) on Windows 10 with:

```
pip install pykeops
```

I get very a famous error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fcntl'
```

I know, that `fcntl` does not exist on Windows, but how to substitute it for KeOps?